# TFS 2012/15 API - 'There is no working folder mapping for ...'

Tags: tfs

When using workspace.GetLocalItemForServerItem() I am getting an exception

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.ItemNotMappedException' occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll
```

with inner exception

```
There is no working folder mapping for $/MyProject/MyProjectSubDir/teambuild/tfsbuild.proj.
```

It works perfectly well on one machine but not on another.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well to get a local item, you need a workspace, with a folder mapping...

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you forget to [create a local workspace](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/create-work-workspaces) mapping with server folder. Please double check it and try again. 
[image]

Comment: if you have the workspace and the map is correct? what else could be?

Comment: @XtianGIS More ways to figure out the issue , please take a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751959/exception-message-there-is-no-working-folder-mapping-for